# Clear Cache without logging in

Tags: 7, users, caching

I added an if statement around the content render php in my page.tpl.php file. Only problem is I made a mistake and accidentally prevented it from rendering content on any page. I cleared the cache and logged out to test it, and realising my mistake I corrected the template file. But now I can't log back in to clear the cache again as my site won't render content and thus won't render the login box.

Can someone give me a way in Drupal 7 to either log in without the login in box (like a way to render the login box separately to the content) or a way to clear the cache?

Comment: If you've got access to the database just run `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` for the `cache` table and all other tables beginning with `cache_`

Comment: If you have drush installed you can do `drush cc` from the terminal while standing in your drupal root.

Comment: In you page tpl just run drupal_flush_all_caches();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution I found in the end was to do it through phpmyadmin. I logged in and emptied any tables that had "cache" at the start of their name. Easy if you don't work in drush.

Comment: Repeating the answer of drupal_stuff_alter in part without *any* additional information is hardly useful, and in my opinion very dismissive of the concept of this site. I can't even begin to assume why you would want to derail people finding this question in the future by posting and accepting an answer that ommits the `drush` method, which takes clearly less time and effort, and on top of which is the intended way.

Answer (score 12):

i. If you have drush installed (http://drupal.org/project/drush) — if you don't have it, think about that next time :), open up the console (WIN+R) in Windows or Ctrl+Alt+T in Linux point to your site folder (e.g. `cd /www/mydrupalsite/` and type:

```
 $ drush cc all
```

from the command line.

ii. Another method is to log into your phpmyadmin select your cache_ tables and flush/empty  them.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the options mentioned above, as a last ditch effort you could call the function `drupal_flush_all_caches()`, to clear all caches.

You may do this by placing the code below in a php file in your document root and visiting it with a browser:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

I have not tested this code, and make sure to remove it after you have cleared your caches.

Comment: Note that you'd need to define the DRUPAL_ROOT constant first. It wasn't showing in the code example originally, so I added some white space so it shows now.

Answer (score 2):

You can set

```
$update_free_access = TRUE;
```

in settings.php (around line 226) and browse to /update.php.  This will clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the Drupal cache by executing the following command either in the Windows command console or from a .bat file (or from the Linux console):

> php -r "define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '../web'); chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT); define('MAINTENANCE_MODE', 'update'); global $_SERVER; $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'; require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/bootstrap.inc'; drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); drupal_flush_all_caches();"

Just make sure that DRUPAL_ROOT in the code points to the Drupal directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from cache where cid <> '';
delete from cache_block where cid <> '';
delete from cache_bootstrap where cid <> '';
delete from cache_field where cid <> '';
delete from cache_filter where cid <> '';
delete from cache_path where cid <> '';
delete from cache_libraries where cid <> '';
delete from cache_image where cid <> '';
delete from cache_page where cid <> '';
delete from cache_token where cid <> '';
delete from cache_update where cid <> '';
delete from cache_views where cid <> '';
delete from cache_views_data where cid <> '';
```